# MSA (protein) with biopython or something else?

Tags: sequence-alignment, proteins, python

I am very new to bioinformatics (and python in general), but I would like to use python to more efficiently analyse enzymes both in terms of structure and functio, using Jupiter notebook. I would like to ask what is the best program/source code for multiple sequence alignments (amino acids) to identify conserved binding sites etc. I see that [biopython](https://biopython.org/docs/1.74/api/index.html#) has a few ways of creating alignments, but I have the impression that it is more focused on nucleotide sequences?

Comment: It works for both —but for global alignments you'd want system calls to something better (`muscle` say) than the inbuilt pairwise method. I don't know about MSA viewers for Jupyter, but I'd like to say that `nglview` is a really nice module to view your 3D protein structure in the notebook —it is despotic to set up at times, but totally worth the struggle.

Comment: Thanks, yea I got nglview to work after some time! Still working on the MSA in python, most sites seem to focus on nucleotide alignments.

Comment: I found [a nice blog post](https://dmnfarrell.github.io/bioinformatics/bokeh-sequence-aligner) about plotting MSAs in Jupyter notebooks, which I thought was relevant to this.

Answer (score 1):

In my personal experience, MUSCLE is the easiest program to use in conjunction with Biopython. Biopython features a [command line wrapper](https://biopython.org/docs/1.75/api/Bio.Align.Applications.html) for this program, which makes it very easy to use. Make sure to [download the appropriate MUSCLE program from drive5](http://www.drive5.com/muscle/downloads.htm) and save it somewhere. E.g., if you are using Jupyter in Linux:

```
!wget https://www.drive5.com/muscle/downloads3.8.31/muscle3.8.31_i86linux64.tar.gz
!tar -xzvf muscle3.8.31_i86linux64.tar.gz
!cp muscle3.8.31_i86linux64 /usr/local/bin
!chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/muscle3.8.31_i86linux64
```

Then, you can run MUSCLE like so:

```
from Bio.Align.Applications import MuscleCommandline
def runMUSCLE(infile, outfile):
    muscle_exe = r"/usr/local/bin/muscle3.8.31_i86linux64" #Here is where we installed MUSCLE
    muscle_cline = MuscleCommandline(muscle_exe,
                                     input=infile,
                                     out=outfile,
                                     clwstrict=True #Output in clustal format (more visually pleasing), otherwise the output is in FASTA. Whichever you need.
                                    )
    muscle_cline()
```

You don't need to specify that your sequence is amino acidic, however keep in mind that the input file must be in FASTA format.